# Is there a name for scrolling by middle click rather than spinning the wheel?

Tags: scrolling

I recently found myself having to describe a problem that happens when you middle mouse click and drag the mouse up/down/left/right to scroll, as opposed to actually spinning the mousewheel.

Is there a common-ish one or two word phrase that differentiates the two without having to explain it? Something like "click-scrolling" vs "spin-scrolling"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"auto-scroll",

> "Auto-scrolling is a feature that can be found in most mainstream modern applications. Pressing the middle mouse button transfers the application into the auto-scrolling mode. In this mode, moving the mouse down starts scrolling down the contents even when the mouse is no longer moving. The scroll speed depends on the distance between the current mouse location and the mouse press location. This works for all four directions (up, down, left, right)."

from http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_autoscroll

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, cheers.

Comment: (To activate it in order to keep scrolling after clicking, just press the middle button for 2 secs without moving the mouse). Then just move up/down your mouse, the scrolling will remain without clicking.